# Why does htop command does not work on *shell*?

Tags: shell, terminal-emacs, term

I tend to prefer `shell` over `term`. With `shell` everything is text and I can use the Emacs bindings to move around.

Also, I have been trying to avoid opening my nixOS terminal. I have been trying to stay in Emacs as much as I can. However, executing `htop` on `*shell*` does **not** work. The image below shows what I get:

[image]

I was expecting what is been retrieved by the `*terminal*` buffer.

[image]

I feel I do not really understand terminal emulators in Emacs.

Why `htop` does not work in `*shell*`? Is there a way to fix this by tweaking my [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el)?

Comment: `htop` uses cursor-motion character sequences to place everything exactly where it wants. `term` interprets those characters as cursor motions and everything works; `shell` does not: it just inserts them into the buffer. IOW, `shell` provides only a "dumb" terminal that does not know how to interpret [ANSI terminal escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M-x term is a terminal emulator. `htop` needs a terminal.

M-x shell is only a shell, *not* a full terminal. Shell commands like `ps` will work but terminal commands like `htop` or `vim` will not.

I agree that shell is more convenient because it's just text, but you'll need a terminal to run terminal commands. When I do need a terminal, I use `vterm` over `term` but it's still inconvenient compared to `shell`.

Answer (score 2):

@NickD and @amitp answers are the correct ones making a distinction between shell and term.

As a side note, `proced` built-in command in Emacs is a good alternative for `htop`. But this point is unrelated to the terminal/shell discussion.

Comment: I agree that `proced` is the right tool for the job!